# Why are complex numbers a primitive numeric type in Go?

Tags: go

Go defines two numeric types for complex numbers, `complex64` and `complex128`. This is rare. Most programming languages define complex numbers as the combination of a real and complex part, rather than including a specific primitive for the purpose. (Even in group theory complex numbers are formally constructed as pairs of reals.) Why did the designers of Go decide that Go needed primitive types for complex numbers?

Comment: C has built-in complex numbers; C99 added them, but C11 made them optional.

Comment: @matthew-piziak, your own observation (in comments below) about Go's omission of an operator overloading feature seems key. You cited: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/7bW5JmUbAB8/-UF5ZV8qGZYJ, and now there is more recent discussion with similar overtones: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19921

Comment: @pestophagous Thanks for bringing up this context! I'm glad I wasn't the only one to be thinking along these lines.

Answer (score 8):

Ken Thompson, one of the principal Go authors, wanted complex numbers in Go and so he added them to the Go language specification and implemented complex numbers for the Go gc compilers.

Comment: Indeed he commented in the discussion I linked earlier (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/7bW5JmUbAB8/rJLvwYzqRmEJ), saying "I am interested in this and hope to do something." Looks like he did.

Comment: It's a shame he stopped there. Complex numbers are useful but could just as easily be done in a library. Rational numbers are also useful and are *only* available in a library. There is an unpleasant imbalance in that the code involved in using rational number looks frankly horrible, whereas complex numbers have nice operators. Operator overloading (at least for the main four + - * /) would have been far more widely useful than baked-in complex number support, IMO. This could have been done via a special interface that any library must meet in order to qualify for the arithmetic operators.

Comment: I agree. Rational numbers are constructed very similarly to complex numbers in group theory, as equivalence classes on number pairs. It doesn't make sense to upgrade one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are dead useful? And: Go complex numbers are just that: A real and imaginary part.

Comment: That doesn't explain why they are defined as a primitive data type rather than being defined as a tuple and wrapped in a mathematics library, as is the case in many other languages.

Comment: Would you like the syntax of math/big/Rat for complex numbers? Probably not. You cannot do `x + y` in Go if `x` and `y` are not primitive types as there is no operator overloading.

Comment: Good point. I found this discussion from before complex primitives were in the language: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/7bW5JmUbAB8/-UF5ZV8qGZYJ. It looks like the lack of operator overloading was indeed an issue in writing clean code using non-native complex numbers. So it seems like complex numbers were added as a primitive - a small design change which brought a lot of benefit. Adding operator overloading would have solved the problem as well, but would have added complexity to the language. If you mention the operator overloading issue in your answer body I'll accept it.